# !important specificity override not working

Tags: html, css, css-specificity

I was designing a nav bar button, when I got a specificity conflict in the opacity. I used the !important override, but that doesn't seem to be working. Any clues as to the reason?

HTML:

```
    <body>
    <div class="container">
        <span id="text">Lorem Ipsum</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
    .container {
            background-color: #000;
            opacity:0;
            height: 30px; 
            width: 122px; 
            -moz-border-radius: 5px;
            -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
            position:absolute;
            top:40%;
            left:43%;
        }

         #text { 
            color: #fff;
            -moz-user-select: none;
            -webkit-user-select: none;
            font-family: Courier;
            position:absolute;
            top: 5px;
            left: 5px;
            width: 122px;
            opacity:1; !important;
        }

        body {
            background-color: #808080;
        }
```

After this all I get is a blank gray background (due to the background-color styling). I know it makes much more sense to *not* nest the span in the div, but I need to do that for animation purposes.

Comment: `!important` isn't the issue here as a selector with an `ID` already has a higher specificity a selector with a `class`.

Answer (score 2):

must be like that :

```
opacity:1 !important;
```

no `;` before `!important`

if `.container` have `opacity:0` then all elements inside this div will not be visible, even if you add `opacity:1 !important;` to `#text`

Comment: @user1305192 you can not hide parent div and show only the child

Answer (score 0):

**First**

Declare `!important` write this `opacity:1 !important;` instead of this  `opacity:1; !important;`.

**Second**

you define Opacity to `#text` **parent** that's why it's take it's parent opacity. So, instead of **opacity**  you can use **RGBA()**.

Write like this:

```
.container {
            background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0);
        }
```

**Filter** for IE

```
background: transparent;
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#00000000,endColorstr=#00000000);   /* IE6 & 7 */      
zoom: 1;
```

Comment: Thanks, that was just the thing I was looking for.